# How do I merge three update query into one single update query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a promotion table with a single update statement. Although the three update statements below can do it, I want to merge the three statements into one. How can I do that?

`UPDATE promos SET next_promotion = (last_promotion + 4) WHERE grade_level IN (14,15,16,17,18)`

`UPDATE promos SET next_promotion = (last_promotion + 3) WHERE grade_level IN (7,8,9,10,11,12,13)`

`UPDATE promos SET next_promotion = (last_promotion + 2) WHERE grade_level IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Comment: [duplicate on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551721/how-do-i-merge-three-update-code-in-sql-into-one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a `CASE` statement like so:

```
UPDATE P
SET P.next_promotion = 
     CASE 
         WHEN P.grade_level IN (14,15,16,17,18) THEN P.last_promotion + 4
         WHEN P.grade_level IN (7,8,9,10,11,12,13) THEN P.last_promotion + 3
         WHEN P.grade_level IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) THEN P.last_promotion + 2
         ELSE P.next_promotion
     END
FROM Promos AS P
WHERE P.grade_level >= 1 
AND P.grade_level <= 18 -- Ensures we only update the records we want to change and doesn't do any extra work updating
```

And this equivalent query minimizes the code (if you're counting characters :).

```
UPDATE Promos
SET next_promotion = 
     CASE 
         WHEN grade_level BETWEEN 14 AND 18 THEN last_promotion + 4
         WHEN grade_level BETWEEN 7 AND 13 THEN last_promotion + 3
         WHEN P.grade_level BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN last_promotion + 2
         ELSE next_promotion
     END
WHERE grade_level BETWEEN 1 AND 18 -- Ensures we only update the records we want to change and doesn't do any extra work updating
```

Comment: Do we really need this part? "FROM Promos AS P
WHERE grade_level >= 1 
AND grade_level <= 18"

Comment: @Pantea lol *great minds think alike*, looks like we were thinking the same thing almost spot on. The `WHERE` clause I added ensures only the records we want updated are actually updated and reduces the amount of work for the `UPDATE` statement. For example if it had 100s of millions of rows, the update would be much heavier without it. In your example, you'll be `NULL`ing out the other records which may not be want OP wants.

Comment: Thanks. So seems like your query works better performance wise :) because of that, I'm gonna up-vote your query .

Comment: Thanks :) you're right.

Comment: @Pantea No problem, good questions! Thanks for the upvote. :)

Comment: `WHERE P.grade_level BETWEEN 1 AND 18` is a tad bit more compact

Comment: @Lennart Good point. Could say the same for each `IN` operator of each `WHEN` clause too. :)

Comment: @ J.D thank you very much, the query worked perfectly.

Comment: @Mohammed Great, no problem! :) Not required, but feel free to accept or upvote the answer so other users with similar questions see it verified as helpful.